# Why is the Design tab in the WindowBuilder editor empty in Eclipse 2020-09?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

After upgrading to Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) in the WindowBuilder editor the Java code is shown in the *Source* tab (as expected), but **nothing is shown in the *Design* tab anymore**. I would expect that the graphical editor would be displayed in the *Design* tab, as it was the case before I did the upgrade.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? What *part of the design*?

Comment: the source code of this WindowApplication is showing and I can programming easily (no problem) but there is no changers if I run the programme in the size (generally in the window ) it keep like default         sorry for my English

Comment: You are looking for the console then.

Comment: I change the version of Eclipse than it works. I think the problem is in the version of JDK or something like that

Answer (score 5):

That's a **known issue** of the Eclipse 2020-09 release which is **already fixed** (see [Eclipse bug 567071](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567071#c7)).

Update to WindowBuilder 1.9.4 either [via the Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder) or via *Help > Install New Software...* and working with the update site [`http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/`](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/).

**Update**: For Java 17 and higher, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250).

Comment: This is not fixed, or the problem was created again since these releases.

Comment: @maxbear123 Java 17 broke it again by being even more restrictive than Java 16: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250