# Java Windowsbuilder is not showing anything in the design tab and no class name in the main tab

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowsbuilder

I created a composite visual class and received the "The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite is not accessible" error. I went into fix project set up and had to manually update the class path. The error has not gone away and the tab doesn't show the class name. The tab is invisible until I hover over it and then an "x" appears to close it.

Additionally half the time when I open the class it doesn't show the option to switch between source and design. If that happens I have to close the workspace and reopen it to get Eclipse to show the source and design tab.

I haven't added any code to the class. It's the skeleton code Eclipse provides when you click "Create New Visual Class -> SWT -> Composite". It's my first time messing with a windows builder. I was really hoping I wouldn't have to manually code all the dimensions in Swing.

[Code and error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnEfy.png)

Comment: Please put your actual code and error in your question; physical code is preferred to links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Design tab in the WindowBuilder editor empty in Eclipse 2020-09?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049891/why-is-the-design-tab-in-the-windowbuilder-editor-empty-in-eclipse-2020-09)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> filter by popular and click install on WindowBuilder. I had a similar error some time ago because I've installed WindowBuiler by installing the separate dependencies instead of click the install button in the marketplace

Comment: I already had WindowBuilder installed, but this lead me to update the program through the marketplace. That fixed the initial problem of tabs not even having the name of the program. I still had the issue of it not compiling. To fix that I followed this advice:

The solution could be to add a Library of execution like explained below

Go to: Project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Execution Environment

Select the drop down list and then choose "javaSE-1.7" (except I chose 1.8)

Thank you so much for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Eclipse.

2.Click on Help.

3.Then go in Eclipse Marketplace.

4.Search for Windowbuilder.

5.Click on Installed button in Windowbuilder 1.9.4.

6.Then click on Update.

7.and Proceed further steps.

### Reference Link:

 https://youtu.be/LgOMN3US6Bk