# WindowBuilder Design Tab incomplete in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I was creating a JFrame for a project and while trying to edit it, the design tab was blank.

I've created a test project with everything on default and this "error" still there.

[image: This is what the design tab shows]

Here's the code of the test:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test frame = new Test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
  }

}
```

And this is what i've done already:

- WindowBuilder is already installed, both 1.9.5 and 1.9.6.pre Nightly Build (i've tried installing only one of them too but no success).
- I have installed all the necessary packages for Swing, including: Swing Designer, All SWT Components, and all WindowBuilder Components.
- I've tried to uninstall and install it again all of those packages and components, but still no success.
- The option "Associate WindowBuilder editor with automatically recognized Java GUI files" on Window>Preferences>WindowBuilder is already checked.

The only thing left would be reinstalling Eclipse which i'm kinda concerned with because of how many plugins i have installed. Reinstalling them would be a pain (kinda of).

Does WindowBuilder have some incompatibilities with some plugin? I have a few for Python and others that is just QoL.

EDIT: Problem solved, for anynone going through that as well, just add `--illegal-access=permit` in the eclipse.ini in the last line.

Comment: Is it [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572210#c3) ? Otherwise, tell both, the Java version used to run Eclipse (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Configuration_) and the Java version used in your project. Did this only happen using the Dark theme or also with the default Light theme?

Comment: I use jdk-16.0.1 in both Eclipse installation and in the project, it's the only version i have installed for now, and yes this "error", if you will, happens on the default classic theme as well, and about that `--illegal-access=permit` argument that you referred, do you know where exactly i should put in my .ini? I'm kinda new to Java and so, Eclipse.

Comment: In the `eclipse.ini` file add `--illegal-access=permit` as last line.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now, thank you a lot! @howlger

Answer (score 14):

This is a known and already fixed issue when running Eclipse with Java 16 or higher:

[WindowBuilder issue #45 - Reflective access with CGLIB breaks windowbuilder in java 16 and higher](https://github.com/eclipse//issues/45)

**Update**: The issue has been fixed. It is already available in the [WindowBuilder Nightly Build](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowbuilder-nightly-build) (update site: [`https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/lastgoodbuild/`](https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/lastgoodbuild/)) and will be available in the upcoming WindowBuilder 1.9.8 release.

Answer (score 0):

Open new project in JavaSE-11 and downgrade window builder to version 1.9.4 and everything will work fine. I have had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

After creating new application, WindowBuilder design view is blank. No pallets, no window displayed when using Java 17, WindowBuilder 1.9.7 and Eclipse 2021-12

**Possible solution(s)- AS PER SUGGESTIONS ABOVE (AND BELOW)**

1. Revert to Java 11 and WindowBuilder 1.9.4 (not ideal)
2. Add --illegal-access=permit to the ini file of Eclipse (Already
   there in the ini file of 2021-12)
3. Update WindowBuilder to the nightly build version 1.9.8.pre
   (Works!!!!)