# Eclipse window builder with blank window and palette

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I have Eclipse recently installed and the version is
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
Build id: 20210312-0638
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 16

WindowBuilder is also installed version 1.9.5 and updated.

I created new Java project and, for example, named it *Employee*. On *Employee* I click right click and go to the bottom where I pick other and scroll down to WindowBuilder and pick Swing Designer- Application window.

Source code in new created Java file is OK. Everything is as it should be but when I click on Design tab all windows are blank (Structure, Palette, Properties) and cannot build anything. As I can see while Googling many people have this problem and there was no idea how to fix it.

I tried reinstalling Eclipse and WindowBuilder but no luck.

[image: source code of java class]
[image: Blank Designer view]
[image: updated Window Builder]

Comment: That's a known issue when running Eclipse with Java 16: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250

Comment: Has been fixed with 1.9.7

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for answer I just realized how to fix this. Go to window builder site and install version 1.9.4.
When opening new project please open in Java 11 only. Will not work in newest jdk

So project in jdk 11 and only 1.9.4 window builder version

Answer (score 0):

version 1.9.5 has completely removed from https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php.
Downloaded and installed the latest version **Current(1.9.7)**.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update both WindowBuilder and WindowBuilder Nightly using market place then it should work fine. It worked for me , give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, I had a similar problem with eclipse 2023-12 and WindowBuilder version 1.15.0.  The application ran and displayed the components fine, but when looking at the Design tab in the WindowBuilder editor, all panels were blank.  Another GUI class in the same project did not have any problems, so there must have been something wrong with that one class.  To find the problem I started removing items one at a time until WindowBuilder worked and displayed the class properly.  I found that I had created a JTable without specifying a model:

```
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames)
```

where rowData and columnNames were specified earlier in the class. Perfectly legal constructor syntax for a JTable.  Unfortunately, WindowBuilder didn't like it, so I changed the code to include a default table model:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel (rowData, columnNames );
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

And, son-of-a-gun, WindowBuilder displayed the table properly.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider [reporting a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WindowBuilder)?