# Eclipse WindowBuilder not showing me anything in design tab

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I had some problems yesterday with Eclipse, so I uninstalled then installed it again, I installed the latest JVM version, and I imported one of my old projects to eclipse, I added the windowBuilder from the eclipse market, but when I click on the design Tab, it doesn't show anything in it, even thought the source code exist, and the GUI works normally when I run the program, but in the design window I cant see anything, any ideas on how to fix it?[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Already answered here [WindowBuilder Design Tab incomplete in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394509/windowbuilder-design-tab-incomplete-in-eclipse) Check it

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions, none worked, any other ideas?

Comment: @HadiHoteit I changed my answer check if my new suggestions work .