# Eclipse windowbuilder not showing the full frame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm trying to use Eclipse windowbuilder, but when I go to the design page the frame gets cut. Below is an image of what I am seeing.
[image: Problem]

This is just a simple JFrame (nothing added besides the default). If I run or preview the window, it shows me the whole frame as it should. For some reason unknown to me, the design tab is just cutting my frame.

I've seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394509/windowbuilder-design-tab-incomplete-in-eclipse), but my eclipse.ini file already has the `--illegal-access=permit` added at the end.

Does anyone know what this might be about? I am using JDK 16 by the way. Sorry if this is somewhat of a newb question, but it is my first time with swing and GUI building in Java.

Comment: This is just a small UI glitch, not a real problem (maybe caused by different or wrong window sizes on Windows 10). Please provide a [patch for it here](https://github.com/eclipse/windowbuilder). The mentioned question is not related.