# Error when opening Design tab in eclipse for JavaFx

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I had to download eclipse for a school assignment in order to create a GUI that check the type of the triangle. I installed all the needed packages from the General Purpose Tools in order to use Swing for building a GUI.
After that I go to my project --> right click --> New --> Other --> Swing Designer --> JFrame.
Writing code manually to create a GUI works but when I switch to the Design tab, I get this error:
Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description.
For component javax.swing.JFrame.
Here is my stack trace:

> org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 502 (Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description.). javax.swing.JFrame
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:442)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:289)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:258)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.createJavaInfo(JavaInfoUtils.java:387)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.parser.ParseFactory.getRootContext(ParseFactory.java:128)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1182)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:242)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4770)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
> at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
> at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
> at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:468)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:392)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:46)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:34)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.JavaExceptionComposite.doRefresh(JavaExceptionComposite.java:87)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4237)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
> at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1041)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
> at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
> at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.String javax.swing.JFrame.paramString() accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens javax.swing" to unnamed module @4dafea3f
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.appendPropertyComponents(ReflectionUtils.java:1560)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(ReflectionUtils.java:1469)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.rules.StandardBeanPropertiesRule.begin(StandardBeanPropertiesRule.java:47)
> at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1563)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1387)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2726)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
> at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
> at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
> at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:389)
> ... 56 more

Full context stack trace:
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 502 (Unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description.). javax.swing.JFrame
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:442)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:289)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:258)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.JavaInfoUtils.createJavaInfo(JavaInfoUtils.java:387)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.parser.ParseFactory.getRootContext(ParseFactory.java:128)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1182)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:242)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4770)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:468)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:392)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:46)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:34)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.JavaExceptionComposite.doRefresh(JavaExceptionComposite.java:87)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4237)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1041)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.String javax.swing.JFrame.paramString() accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens javax.swing" to unnamed module @4dafea3f
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.appendPropertyComponents(ReflectionUtils.java:1560)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.reflect.ReflectionUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(ReflectionUtils.java:1469)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.rules.StandardBeanPropertiesRule.begin(StandardBeanPropertiesRule.java:47)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1563)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1387)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2726)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.description.helpers.ComponentDescriptionHelper.getDescription0(ComponentDescriptionHelper.java:389)
... 56 more

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's a known issue when running Eclipse with Java 16 or 17 that is already fixed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250 By the way, please format log/output/code as _Code Sample_ instead of _Blockquote_ to prevent line breaks.