# WindowBuilder was not able to show the GUI. unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description for component javax.swing.JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

I'm using Eclipse 2021-9 version and already have windowbuilder installed. this error happens when I click the designer tab. Can anybody help me?

[image: Error dialog]

Comment: Which version of WindowBuilder? Could you reproduce this issue with a fresh Eclipse 2021-09 without additional installed plugins, only with the WindowBuilder plugin and a fresh workspace? If yes, please show a minimal Java file with which it can be reproduced.

Comment: The WindowBuilder version is the most recent one, I got from the oficial website. Actually this is a new Eclipse, I reinstalled it, so there is no plugins beyond WindowBuilder. Thanks for answering!

Comment: This may not be related at all, but in the Preferences look at 'Java > Appearance > Type Filters' and clear any filter for 'java.awt.*'

Comment: Then please show a minimal Java file with which it can be reproduced.

Comment: Did you import files or workspaces from an older version of Eclipse?

Comment: Same issue here - fresh new Eclipse install and WB just crashed with same error

Comment: @AlexByrth Which WB version do you have and with which Java version do you run Eclipse? There are issues with Java 16 and 17 that have already been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I just updated WindowBuilder Nightly Build 1.9.6.pre instalation and the problem was solved.

Comment: You mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250

Comment: Just had the same issue! Updating WindowBuilder Nightly 1.9.6.pre worked for me too!

Comment: Omg it actually worked, thank you!!

Comment: *"it actually worked"* Please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

> 1. Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace>
> 2. Search "Window Builder"

Output:

[image]

Click on Installed of  **Window Builder nightly build 1.9.8.pre**

Output:

If there is update then click on it.

[image]