# On Java 17 WindowBuilder was not able to show the GUI. .wbp-component.xml description for component javax.swing.JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder, java-17

I'm using Eclipse 2021-9 version and already have Window builder installed. this error happens when I click the designer tab.

> WindowBuilder was not able to show the GUI. unable to load
> *.wbp-component.xml description for component javax.swing.JFrame

Can anybody help me?

I am running Java 17 on Macbook Pro M1 Max 16" and Monterey 12.0.1

I looked up this thread:

[WindowBuilder was not able to show the GUI. unable to load *.wbp-component.xml description for component javax.swing.JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927269/windowbuilder-was-not-able-to-show-the-gui-unable-to-load-wbp-component-xml-d)

I followed all the steps exactly, but still I am getting this error.

I also tried the steps given in this link: [WindowBuilder Design Tab incomplete in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394509/windowbuilder-design-tab-incomplete-in-eclipse/67430120#67430120)

But I am still getting the same error

Here is my error: [Error Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi41l.png)

Here is what I have tried according to the previous post:

[Installed latest version of Window Builder Nightly Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCBsb.jpg)

Please note: As I am a new user, I am not allowed to embed images in my post, so I have posted the link for it.

Comment: Use Java -16 or below . Windowbuilder cannot run java-17 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse. After installing Eclipse, first install only windows builder & then install rest of the plugins as required.

Comment: @Mori Self-answering questions is perfectly fine, and is even encouraged. Solutions should be posted as answers, and not as additions to the question, even if the OP managed to solve the problem on their own. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center.