# WindowBuilder 1.9.5 not showing design tab after re import project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

After several test I found that this that I did previously in another project is not working. In fact, a project I worked on a few months ago shows me this error of not showing the design tab.

- Create SWT/JFace Java Project
- Add Swing designer->JFrame
- The desing tab is visible
- Remove project from workspace
- Import the project
- The desing tab is not available

I am using:

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

Some screenshots of what I said before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

¿Is this a bug or I am doing some wrong? A similar problem exists with WindowBuilder (08/2020-09/2020) but were fixed in previous version according comments. Thanks

EDIT: Solved

Comment: Just a guess, but try checking the projects facets (right click on project -> configure facets).

Comment: If you are using Java 16 or later then it is [the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67394509/2670892)

Comment: According to the screenshot, you opened `MainFraime.java` with the regular Java editor instead of the WindowBuilder editor: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/features/editing_existing_window.html

Comment: @howlger I have not that option (https://imgur.com/a/RKfcJ1T). While the project is not deleted from workspace I can closed it and open it (just with double clic) and the design tab is visible. But once I remove and reload the error appear

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have not that option (https://imgur.com/a/g9A8tkA)

Comment: Right-click the `MainFraime.java` file and choose _Open With > WindowBuilder Editor_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the screenshot, you opened the `MainFraime.java` file with the regular **Java editor instead of** the **WindowBuilder** editor.

**Right-click** the file and choose ***Open With > WindowBuilder Editor*** (see [WindowBuilder Pro User Guide - Editing Existing Windows](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/features/editing_existing_window.html)).

Please note, [since Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) *Open With > ...* no longer remembers the chosen editor to open that file next time](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.18/platform.php#store-default-editor). This means double-clicking a file always opens the file with the default editor which is for `*.java` files the regular Java editor, not the WindowBuilder editor.