# Did I correctly install WindowBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder

I try to use the  WindowBuilder (https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) to edit the following codes.
But when I open the following file with windowBuilder, there are no buttons as following image. Did I correctly install WindowBuilder?

I have installed the problematic version 1.9.5, because eclipse maket place searched it as follows. On the other hand, from the above site, the version 1.9.5 was removed. I am confused, where eclipse get 1.9.5.

Eclipse market place
[image]

Site (https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php)

[image]

Comment: Does the following help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250

Comment: I am not sure but it may be a possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

1. In eclipse, open  Help >   eclipse Mareketplace.
2. Find windowbuilder
3. Update windowbuilder from installed version to "WindowBuilder Nightly Build 1.9.6 pre" by hit the button which is now `installed`, but before update, the button was `update`. Then windowBuilder will work fine.

**NOTE**
I have tried remove all eclipse files and reinstall eclipse and also uninstall and reinstall window builder with several existing versions, but the error occured.

[image]